# Using {% in jinja2 templates

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a jinja2 template which contain value:

```
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %P%5p {%c}- %x %m %n
```

Since {%c} is treated as an expression, it is throwing an error. Is there any way to tell jinja2 not to render {%c}?

I want the final output contain {%c}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Escaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escaping) section of the manual, you can just output it like this:

```
{{ '{%c}' }}
```